# Error when writing data to binary file c++ qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a c++ qt program and I need to write data to a binary file. But there's a problem. When I do this, extra empty bytes are written to the file. Here is my code:

```
QDataStream output(&fileOut);
QBitArray result;
result.resize(8);
result.fill(true);
output << result;
```

As a result, my file consists of 5 bytes instead of 1:

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00001000
11111111
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't use `qt`, but for standard C++, you have to use the stream's `write` function to specify the exact number of bytes to write, and not use `<<`.  This is especially the case if you're writing the file as "binary", where you need total control of how many bytes are written.

Comment: What's your definition for fileOut?

Comment: It's not a problem since you are trying to write an array. Extra 4 bytes those are written at the beginning are used to store a length of array. If you want to avoid this, you should convert the data of your bit array to another data type, qint8 for example, which one is 1 byte length

Answer (score 2):

Using QDataStream to write binary data in any form which should not be read again by QDataStream will not work since QDataStream adds some more bytes to be able to deserialize the data later on. QDataStream is not meant to write plain data (as can be seen in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#details)) - use [QFile::write()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) for it.

Comment: Do you really think so? `A data stream is a binary stream of encoded information which is 100% independent of the host computer's operating system, CPU or byte order. For example, a data stream that is written by a PC under Windows can be read by a Sun SPARC running Solaris.` So it's universal and do not mislead people

Comment: `So it's universal and do not mislead people` - yes, it's universal in the way that it can be read and write from/to QDataStream on different platforms. But it's data format is not specified so you can not read it with something without known the Qt internals.

Comment: You can read and write without any restrictions. You do not need to know how it is realized in Qt. For example QTcpSocket is realized on top of QDataStream, but it works with any socket

Comment: `For example QTcpSocket is realized on top of QDataStream,` - no, QTcpSocket does not use QDataStream at all - you can send your data encoded as a QDataStream through a QTcpSocket but you have to read it on the other side with QDataStream too.

Comment: `For example QTcpSocket is realized on top of QDataStream, but it works with any socket`. I should be more correct, i wanted to say, that QDataStream `provides serialization of binary data to a QIODevice`, while `QIODevice provides both a common implementation and an abstract interface for devices that support reading and writing of blocks of data, such as QFile, QBuffer and QTcpSocket`. So you are free to use QDataStream to write/read to/from any stream without worry how this data would be read on another end.

Comment: `So you are free to use QDataStream to write/read to/from any stream without worry how this data would be read on another end` - no, this is not the case - as stated many times here already QDataStream adds additional data used for later deserialization! And it's not publicity documented what is added so you can't use QDataStream on one side and plain data access on the other.

Comment: I do read and write from/to socket that is served by win32 application, written on C++ Builder, with QDataStream and all works fine, no extra data is written!!!

Comment: It works as long as you use PODs but as soon as you add e.g. a char* then 4 extra bytes are added at the front for the length (see e.g. [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/serialization/qdatastream.cpp#n1060)), the same is true for containers. Also in older versions (u)int64 [was encoded](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/serialization/qdatastream.cpp#n891) not as you would expect. So it works by accident for you and might change in future versions.

Comment: Pre-writing size of the variadic length data is a basic way for storing such one. Int64 in the source is simply splitter to two int32 and they are written consequently, so the original  byte order is preserved, it's equivalent to writing all 8 bytes of int64 at once

Answer (score 0):

There may be some under the hood conversion shenanigans w/ qBitArray being sent to a stream.

- Try converting qBitArray to qint8
- If that fails, fry converting qBitArray to qByteArray. Then maybe also to qint8

[QDatastream](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html) resource
[image]